# Что такое сервисы и зачем их добавлять?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Всем доброго здоровья! Начинаю изучать ASP.NET Core, там, в рамках шаблона Web API, присутствует класс `Startup`, в котором определен метод `ConfigureServices()`.
Может ли кто-нибудь простыми словами объяснить какие сервисы он настраивает, и для чего они могут понадобиться? Спасибо!

Comment: Какие сервисы _вам_ нужны, те и указываете там. Например, сериализатор, логгер, соединение с базой данных. В каждом приложении будут свои собственные сервисы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, когда я писал настольные приложения, все эти вещи описывались в отдельных классах и использовались довольно просто. Мой вопрос состоит в том, что непонятно для чего такая конструкция существует.